# How to concatenate with MultiIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes like this:

```
df1

ID      Value1      Amount2
1        100         10
2        400         20
3        300         50
```

```
df2

ID      Value1     Amount2
2        200         20
3        300         30
```

I want to get a table like this form these two dfs.

```
Desired Output:

ID      Value        Amount       Difference_Value         Difference_Amount
      df1    df2    df1   df2        
1     100     0     10     0            100                      10
2     400    200    20    20            200                       0
3     300    300    50    30             0                       20
```

I am a bit new to Multilevel index. I know this is possible but didn't find other questions helpful for my need.

I need this `Value, Amount, Difference_Value and Difference_amount` columns to be merged cells in excel so that I need to know this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if  `MultiIndex` for all columns:

First convert `ID` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), subtract by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last for change `MultiIndex` is used [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')

df3 = df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0)

df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=(['df1','df2', 'diff']))
        .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
        .fillna(0)
        .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
   Amount2             Value1              
       df1   df2  diff    df1    df2   diff
ID                                         
1       10   0.0  10.0    100    0.0  100.0
2       20  20.0   0.0    400  200.0  200.0
3       50  30.0  20.0    300  300.0    0.0
```

If try join together `MultiIndex` and no `MultiIndex` Dataframes, get tuples instead `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')

df3 = df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0)

df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=(['df1','df2']))
        .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
        .fillna(0)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .join(df3.add_prefix('Diff_')))
print (df)
    (Amount2, df1)  (Amount2, df2)  (Value1, df1)  (Value1, df2)  Diff_Value1  \
ID                                                                              
1               10             0.0            100            0.0        100.0   
2               20            20.0            400          200.0        200.0   
3               50            30.0            300          300.0          0.0   

    Diff_Amount2  
ID                
1           10.0  
2            0.0  
3           20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) then split in column using [`pd.index.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`pd.Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) for assigning difference values.

```
d = df.merge(df1,how='outer',on='ID',suffixes=('-df1','-df2')
).fillna(0)
d
   ID  Value1-df1  Amount2-df1  Value1-df2  Amount2-df2
0   1         100           10         0.0          0.0
1   2         400           20       200.0         20.0
2   3         300           50       300.0         30.0
d = d.assign(diff_value = d['Value1-df1'].sub(d['Value1-df2']),
             diff_amount = d['Amount2-df1'].sub(d['Amount2-df2'])).set_index('ID')
d
    Value1-df1  Amount2-df1  Value1-df2  Amount2-df2  diff_value  diff_amount
ID
1          100           10         0.0          0.0       100.0         10.0
2          400           20       200.0         20.0       200.0          0.0
3          300           50       300.0         30.0         0.0         20.0
```

Now, split the column at `'-'` with `expand=True` for getting `MultiIndex` then use [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

```
d.columns = d.columns.str.split('-',expand=True) #expand= True makes it MultiIndex
d.sort_index(axis=1)

   Amount2       Value1        diff_amount diff_value
       df1   df2    df1    df2         NaN        NaN
ID
1       10   0.0    100    0.0        10.0      100.0
2       20  20.0    400  200.0         0.0      200.0
3       50  30.0    300  300.0        20.0        0.0
```